# Youtube video blocked on mobile bypass

Tags: android, html, youtube, video-streaming, android-webview

Is there anyway to bypass the blocked videos on mobile? First I tried to fire up normal youtube intent, then I used `WebView` (using both `video` and `iframe` tags), and lastly I changed the user agent of `WebView` to a desktop client but none of the above mentioned way worked. I tried `rtsp` to stream the video using `VideoView` but it would only give me a low quality 3gp video, which is what Youtube API gives.

I am running out of options. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same thing with some of our videos on YouTube and found out that only YouTube controls if it will be allowed to show on a mobile. We never found a work-around for it other than hosting the video on our server or using Vimeo. But as it stands,YouTube has control over mobile viewing. Also do you have that video monetized? Monetizing a video on YouTube can also cause them to not allow it on mobile especially if it has any content that YouTube is saying is a Third Party or Copyright infringement. They told us we had third party content when it was all shot by us. Further reading in that problem showed that YouTube's new digital fingerprint is the main culprit for creating a new wave of problems for users trying to upload their own videos they made and own. i.e., a user tried to upload a video of his backyard with birds in it and the birds were singing. When he tried to upload it, YouTube said it was Copyrighted! How do you Copyright bird chirps everyone is now asking!
So try Vimeo or use your own server to deliver the content. Sorry I can't offer more help.

Comment: thanks for your answer Gilmore. Actually the content is hosted by someone else and we were trying to play the videos aggregated by some criteria. This is bizzare, I was hoping there would be a workaround for this. The thing I don't understand is why does changing user agent string in WebView not work? is it because YouTube does some checking before streaming its video?

Comment: and also, using `video` or `iframe` tags for UIWebView for iOS works great... so I think the restriction is in Android device itself rather than YouTube

Comment: I remember being able to bypass the block as a user by asking the desktop version of the YouTube site and then watching the video with the (not updated anymore) Flash Player for Android. So maybe you could try pretending to be the Flash Player when asking for the video from your app. Maybe use a network sniffer to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I remember being able to bypass the block as a user by asking the desktop version of the YouTube site and then watching the video with the (not updated anymore) Flash Player for Android. So maybe you could try pretending to be the Flash Player when asking for the video from your app. Maybe use a network sniffer to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

User "OMA" gave an answer (use 'Desktop Mode'), that sometimes works and is easy to try.

Next up is this Site (or a similar one): http://www.mobileyt.com/ which accepts an URL, then shows your Video.

A Proxy Server *might* assist you with access, particularly if it is a 'Country Restriction' (for Mobile, but does not mention the Country Restriction only the Mobile one). Any ADs served to that Country may be poorly received (Language / Customs); so it is blocked.

You can try a Spoofing Application for your Mobile Browser (Hint: Spoof you Browse with the Opera Browser OR use Explorer 10 on WinXP they won't be ready for that).

Combining those techniques can assist in difficult cases. You can also resort to downloading the Video and playing it with MX Player or VLC (for Mobile).

Good luck, and if at first you don't succeed ...